# How to connect to the databases from netbean 7.0.1

Tags: java, netbeans

I'm using a 64 bit Windows and trying to connect to the database but it shows the following message:

> `java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified`

Anybody could help me to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Please specify , as to which version of SQL you are trying to connect to. If it's SQL Server 2008 R2, then the following code might help you. Here mywebsitedb is the name of the Database created in MS SQL 2008, with username = sa and password = thatstrue. that I had created. But first, as said above, you have to make one Data Source, for which steps are as follows :

1. By going into the Administrative Tools in Control Panel, open Data Sources (ODBC).
2. Under User DSN tab, click Add.
3. Inside the Create New Data Source Window Select SQL Server and click Finish.
4. Inside Create New Data Source to SQL Server, provide any name to the Data Source and   description, the Server Name must be the one to
   which you connect to while launching MS SQL Management Studio and
   click next.
5. On the New Window, Select With SQL Server Authentication and check the Checkbox for "Connect to SQL Server to obtain default
   settings", and provide your username and password in the respective
   fields and click Next.
6. On the New Window, check the Checkbox for "Change the default Database to", and Select your database from the list and click Next.
7. On the New Window click Finish.
8. ODBC Microsoft SQL Server Setup Window will open. Click Test Data Source, if everything is alright, you will see the Message
   saying "TEST COMPLETED SUCCESSFULLY!". Press OK and OK again.

You are setUp to connect to your database now.

```
    import java.sql.Connection;
    import java.sql.DriverManager;
    import java.sql.SQLException;

    public class EstablishConnection
    {
      public Connection getConnectionObject()
      {
        try
        {      
          Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
          Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;database=mywebsitedb;user=sa;password=thatstrue;");

         return con;
        }
        catch(SQLException e)    
        {
          System.err.println("Hello Connecting not possible.");
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to declare your Datasource in the ODBC Management on your computer :

```
Administrative Tools - Data Sources (ODBC)
```

You have to create a Datasource, specifying a driver, database name / login / password and then use this Datasource name in your code.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to connect to Access using the JDBC-ODBC driver, you might want to check your runtime JAR.  I don't believe Oracle bundles it into the 64-bit version of the JDK.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a Data Source for accessing it. You can make it in by going to `Control Panel -> Administrative Tools - > DataSources` and then making data source for ODBC.

Alongwith this you will need a Driver file (.jar) for your database. you need to put it in your classpath or add to your project.

Comment: have done with those things but it still cant run... using the microsoft access 2007 and the database engine has changed to 2007 version. has been trying with many solutions...its that the path not set correctly??

Answer (score -1):

Administrative Tools - Data Sources (ODBC)

You have to create a Datasource, specifying a driver, database name / login / password and then use this Datasource name in your code.